# AWS ELB health check endpoint for Sonatype Nexus OSS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, nexus3

I want to setup a classic AWS ELB in front of an EC2 instance running Nexus OSS. I got the app running an can access http://IPaddress:8081. I now want to put a classic load balancer in front of it. On the ELB's "Health Check" tab, what should be the value of the "Ping path?" I have it set to "/index.html", making the ensuing Ping target value to "HTTP:8081/index.html" but it's not passing health check?

Edit:
According to the [Nexus load balancing page](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/high-availability/load-balancing), it should be http://IPaddress:port/service/rest/v1/status, and I set that to no avail, that is, instance on the ELB's Instances tab still shows OutOfService. I can curl that endpoint and get a HTTP 200, so it's not making sense to me why health check is not passing.

Thanks!

Comment: Since its HTTP communication, why can't you use [ALB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html)?.

Comment: I converted my ELB to ALB

Comment: so, the issue resolved or happening with ALB as well?

Answer (score 1):

Per AWS support, the security group I was using did not allow port 8081 so the ALB health check was failing. Once I added this rule, health check passes. What threw me off is I was able to curl via this port.